# Java factory with generics type

Tags: java, generics

I am doing a project for my university and I am having a problem.

Basically, the project consists of a client-server application and I thought to create a Packet class for the communication. The Packet is made by a Header and a Body. Now there is the problem. I can have some different kind of body but all of them inherit the generic class Body.

My idea is to make a Packet class like this:

```
public class Packet <T extends Body>{
    private Header header;
    private T body;
}
```

and a Header class like this:

```
public class Header {
    private OPS op;
}
```

Now I'd want to have a kind of factory that when I call the method Factory.createPacket() from the server's main, it build a Packet in this way:

1. Read a Header from a SocketChannel
2. Based on a header's field, it'll read a body of that type

For example, if it read a CREATE (a kind of OPS) operation on the header, it should read a CreateBody (that inherit Body)

Furthermore, each body has to have a function that allows getting a body of that type from SocketChannel and this is the reason why I thought to use generics.

Can someone tell me the better way to do that?

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you post two sample usages from client and server? And in which way do you think that `public class Packet <T extends Body>{
    private Header header;
    private T body;
}` could help you instead of `public class Packet {
   private Header header;
   private Body body;
}`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you really want to use generics here. This only helps you if you go all-in. If you go this route, your end goal should be to rely on the compiler to detect when you mix some `Header` with the wrong type of `Body`. And this means the `Header` should be parameterized too.

Your `Header` is ultimately the one deciding the `Body` type. Since it embeds this knowledge, it would probably be best if it actually made this information available to the type system, i.e. `Header<T extends Body>`.

For this to work, you'll need to somehow figure out this type `T` from within the Header, based on the `OPS` instance. So `OPS` would itself need to be a parameterized type.

If `OPS` is an `enum`, it can't be parameterized, so that can't be done in a type-safe fashion (i.e. without explicit casts at some point); so you'll have to add a method like:

```
Class<? extends Body> bodyType();
```

So each `OPS` instance will be bound to a body type internally (but you can't make this visible as such). Someone will need to cast this to a specific body type down the road; and that would probably be your `Header`:

```
class Header<T extends Body> {
    private final Class<T> bodyType;
    public Header(OPS ops) {
        // any type-safety feeling gets blown here!
        this.bodyType = (Class<T>) ops.bodyType();
    }
    // ...
}
```

The only way to keep it safe is to make `OPS` itself parameterized as `OPS<T extends Body>` and instantiate each OPS type by hand (as enums do not support this).

---

If this looks cumbersome, that's kind of intentional. It was primarily meant to discourage you from using generics, as my guess is you really don't need them here. To validate this, look for any reference in your code declared as `Packet<SpecificBodyType>` that couldn't be used just as good if it was merely `Packet`.

Given that you can treat any `Body` subtype as the top-level `Body` abstraction, the `OPS` can be bound to a specific `Body` subclass (internally), exactly as described above: `Class<? extends Body> bodyType();`. So you can make use of that specific class *at runtime*, where it's actually needed.

Alternatively, `OPS` could be a `Function<SocketChannel, Body>`, so it will just decide on its own which `Body` subtype to use within each `apply()` implementation. But nobody else in your program will ever have to care about concrete `Body` subtypes, if:

1. they're not actually needed at compile-time
2. there's a non-trivial effort to refactor your code into making the link between `OPS` types and body types available for the compiler to check.

Comment: I'm really not sure to understand what you said (I am new in Java), but the problem is that I thought to create a function like getFromSocket which initialized the object from the socket. Without using generics I have to write the same code for each class that extends body with the only difference to cast the incoming packet as the type of that class.